# How to use rule in gitlab-ci

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, pipeline, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm trying to build a job that can be conditionally executed depends on whether the files or subdirectories in `WebClient` is modified in `develop` branch, using `rules`. If there are changes found in the develop branch only, then a pipeline will be built.

Currently what I got in my `.gitlab-ci.yml` is

```
deploy_dev_client:
  stage: client
  tags:
    - my tags
  script:
    - '& cd WebClient'
    - 'npm rebuild node-sass'
    - 'npm install @angular/cli@7.0.3'
    - '& npm run build-release --max_old_space_size=$NODE_MEMORY_SIZE'

  rules:
    - changes:
      - WebClient/**/*
      when: always
    - when: never
```

However, after testing, I realized that the pipeline is executed whenever I push something from my local repo to gitlab, even at the other side branches.

I have tried using `only:-develop'`, however it results in `yaml invalid` error, maybe due to not being able to use `only` if `rules` has already been used. Is there anyway I can still using `rules` to target only `develop` branch?

Answer (score 14):

In this link:

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#ruleschanges

They write that `rules: changes` should work exactly like `only/except`. If you read about `only/except`, there are a few strange things with it:

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#using-onlychanges-without-pipelines-for-merge-requests

> When pushing a new branch or a new tag to GitLab, the policy always evaluates to true.

To get around this and only run your job on the development branch, you should be able to combine an `if` with `changes`:

```
deploy_dev_client:
  stage: client
  tags:
    - my tags
  script:
    - '& cd WebClient'
    - 'npm rebuild node-sass'
    - 'npm install @angular/cli@7.0.3'
    - '& npm run build-release --max_old_space_size=$NODE_MEMORY_SIZE'

  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME== "development"'
      changes:
      - WebClient/**/*
      when: always
```

(I haven't tested this code, so let me know if it is all wrong!)